# How Dummy Variables Should Be Modeled In A Linear Regression Model?

Tags: linear-regression, prediction, dummy-variables

I've a cross sectional model where I want predict number of users that take specific service, to make it I've many variables but have specifically two nominal: isWorkday(0 or 1) and weeday(1,2,3,...,7). When I make the model, taking into account the two variables, generates high multicollinearity. So I've delete one of them, so what's better have many dummies (weeday) or less dummies (isWorkday).

Comment: Have you tried both? Usually when faced with this kind of dilema we perform tests with our available options, unless the amount of tests needed create a effort in which the experiment is not worth of.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte you are right, see what I answered next, and I know that all possible models should be tried, but the question is addressed to multicollinearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your task is to predict something, the better variable is the one that gives you a higher prediction accuracy. So you can simply test both and choose the one with which your model performs better.

However, I would suggest considering to engineer your own feature that incorporates information of both variables. For example, you could create three dummy variables: *workday*, *weekend* and *holiday* and include two of them into your model (to prevent falling into the [dummy variable trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)#Incorporating_a_dummy_independent)). Another option would be to only include the interaction terms between *isWorkday* and *weekday*.

Comment: I get it. But if it's the case where I've a dummy variable for isWorkday and six for the days of the weeks(isTuesday,isWednesday,isThurday, isFriday,isSaturday and isSunday) and both in the multicollinearity tests generate conflict , which dummy I should choose isWeekDay or the six dummies?. Remember that I can make a relationship with two variables (multicolineality): isTuesday,isWednesday,isThurday and isFriday mapped to isWorkday(1) and isSaturday and isSunday to isWorkday(0).

Comment: To make a decision, you first test both options. **Case 1:** If *isWorkday* gives you better prediction results, you choose *isWorkday*. **Case 2:** If the six weekday-variables give you better prediction results, you choose the six weekday-variables. **Case 3:** If the six weekday-variables perform equally good as *isWorkday*, you choose *isWorkday*, because in this case, you end up with a smaller model.

Comment: Oh, I understand thanks, with that you tell me I'm also convinced that this would be the way to proceed.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.